# NiceTabularX is not of the full text width

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I'm trying to use nicematrix package for my tables, here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=2cm, headsep=0.5cm, 
showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I compile this with LuaLaTeX, 3 times. One can see the tables are not of the full width of text, and the table in header is a little narrower as compared with the the table in text.

[image]

I also tried with tabularray package, there it works as expected, but tabularray has issue with color tables (border lines can disappear in pdf readers, so I dicided to study nicematrix). Can this width issue of nucematrix be fixed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, during the compilations, the width of `\pageref{LastPage}` changes: first, `\pageref{LastPage}` is equal to `??`. Then, it is equal to `1`. `nicematrix` does not realize that the width of the last column has changed, hence the error.

I suggest to fix the width of the element `\pageref{LastPage}` by writing:

`\makebox[6mm][l]{\pageref{LastPage}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=2cm, headsep=0.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \makebox[6mm][l]{\pageref{LastPage}} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \makebox[6mm][l]{\pageref{LastPage}} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: the fix works, thank you! I thought that nicematrix can solve all the widths during successive runs, but it's OK to set the width in advance.

Comment: @Alx: I will try to improve `nicematrix`. Maybe that problem won't appear in a future version.

Comment: I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` which solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.1 of 2021-08-20), you have directly (after several compilations) the expected result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=2cm, headsep=0.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \makebox[6mm][l]{\pageref{LastPage}} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{clX[12]X[20]l}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm, width=1.3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}} & \Block[l]{}{Organization} & \Block[l]{2-1}{Document type: \\ Document description} & \Block[l]{2-1}{File name: \\ Here-is-long-file-name-with-version\_1.0} & \Block[l]{}{Date: \\ 01.01.2000} \\
 & \Block[l]{}{Some text \\ 1234567890} & & & Page \thepage\ of \makebox[6mm][l]{\pageref{LastPage}} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Yes, I checked -- it works. Many thanks!